# What extender can I use with the Canon TS 24mm?

Tags: lens, canon, teleconverter, tilt-shift

Is there an extender for the Canon TS 24mm? I heard it is possible to make it a 45mm but I can't find much information on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Canon 1.4x and 2x extenders work - more information [here](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-TS-E-24mm-f-3.5-L-II-Tilt-Shift-Lens-Review.aspx) (search within the page for **extender**). Additionally, fitting this on a 1.6x crop-sensor body will give an equivalent of 38.4mm focal length. This route would avoid the incorrect aperture reporting issues, and potentially offer better image quality than when using an extender - if you happen to have access to a crop-sensor body of course.

Comment: Ah, this is surprising... I haven't looked at the rear of my 24 TS/E mk I in a while, it never occurred to me that it might have room for a Canon converter!

Comment: Apparently they do (with several caveats) with the mkII version, it's a significantly different design to the mkI though so I'm guessing there will be even more caveats - if it works at all.

Answer (score 1):

Canon teleconverters won't fit because they have a protruding front element that needs a corresponding recess in the host lens, which only the Canon L-series teles have, but third-party ones from Tamron and others should fit. Not Sigmas, they have similar design to the Canons. Optical quality is another matter, it is usually desireable to stop down a bit to mask the quality loss with a teleconverter installed. And frankly I have no idea if this will work at all if you tilt or shift the lens... Actually, I have the Canon 24mm tilt-shift at home (mkI, but it should make no difference), and a 1.4x converter, so I might just try this out for laughs.

Anyway, assuming that it works, a 1.4x converter would make the 24mm into a 34mm, a 2x will make it a 48mm. With corresponding loss of one or two f-stops, respectively. The 24mm f/3.5 will become a 34mm f/5, or a 48mm f/6.3, or something like that, anyway. And as said it is usual to stop down a bit to regain a bit of the lost sharpness and contrast with a teleconverter in place.

Comment: And apparently, yes, the mkI version has been tested with the 1.4x (again, with caveats regarding reporting of the aperture) - http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-TS-E-24mm-f-3.5-L-Tilt-Shift-Lens-Review.aspx